# It's possible to join two selectors with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm designing a nav and I use the "active" tag to modify its CSS and know what content to show. 
So I decided to implement a jquery function that gets the "active nav-link" and with the $this selector I need to get the text (in particular the href url) shown.
It's possible to concatenate the &this selector with another query to get that text (href url)?

[Nav image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjlR3.png)

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="kid_list">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a t-attf-href="/califications/{{active_kid.id}}" t-attf-class="nav-link active"><t t- 
  esc="active_kid.name"/>
   <span class="badge badge-pill float-right">25</span>
  </a>
 </li>
....
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  $('#kid_list > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#kid_list > li > a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    /*Get the text data ...*/ 
    var url = $(this)

  });
});
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It's not clear what value you're trying to retrieve from the HTML. However it doesn't look like you need to join any selectors. Can you show the actual HTML output, as the 'HTML' in the question looks like it's from a pre-processor of some type.

Comment: With find() function and text() function the problem is solved. Thanks for your replies.