# Obtain text value from a DOM specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to obtain an element of the DOM witch contains some specific text, but the object I'm trying to obtain is undefined.

I need to obtain the "a" tag (parent element) of the "span" tag which contains the text stored in the variable "current_id".
The current_id refers to the text outputed in the tag "t t-esc="active_kid.id" />".

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column" id="kid_list">
 <li class="nav-item">
  <a t-attf-href="/califications/{{active_kid.id}}" t-attf-class="nav-link active"><t t- 
  esc="active_kid.name"/>
   <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: none;"><t t-esc="active_kid.id" /> 
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
```

```
var current_id = window.location.pathname.replace('/califications/','');
if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(current_id, 10))){
 var object = $('#kid_list > li > a > span:contains(${current_id})');
 var a = $(object).parentElement;
}
```

Outputed HTML code:

```
<li class="nav-item">
 <a href="/califications/14" class="nav-link">Azure Interior
  <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: 
  none;">14</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: where is the id current_id in the code that you have provided here

Comment: The current_id referes to the <t t-esc="active_kid.id" /> outputs text. @IshwarGagare

Comment: As per [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660036/its-possible-to-join-two-selectors-with-jquery), we need to see the actual HTML output, not the pre-processed template code, in order to help you debug this

Comment: Does the same templating system also replace the `${current_id}` inside the JavaScript string? I have a feeling that that should be `...span.contains('+current_id+')');`

Comment: Yea it's is replaced by a number @MrLister

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to retrieve the `a` element which is the parent of the `span` which contains the text value held in the `current_id` variable? Is that right?

Comment: Hey, if the href of the a also ends in the same id number, using `a[href$='...']` would be much more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the parent `a` element of the `span` which contains the text matching the value of `current_id` you can use a combination of the `:contains` selector along with `closest()`. Try this:

```js
var current_id = '14'; // window.location.pathname.replace('/califications/', '');

var $a = $('span.badge:contains("' + current_id + '")').closest('a');
$a.addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/califications/14" class="nav-link">
      Foo bar
      <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: none;">12</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="/califications/14" class="nav-link">
      Azure Interior
      <span class="badge badge-pill float-right" style="display: none;">14</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However, given that your `window.location.pathname` appears to already contain the value held in the `href` attribute of the `a` you could simplify this and just select by the attribute on that element directly:

```
var $a = $('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]');
```

Comment: When I take then object I run the function addClass("active") to make it the active nav item. But when I make a redirection this active item desapears. Do you know any way to mantain this item active?? @Rory McCrossan

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a question or a statement?

Comment: It's a question to ask if you know any way to make a redirection and mantain the same "active nav item". @Rory McCrossan

Comment: To redirect the page (presumably to the `href` of that `a` element) use `window.location.assign()`. To keep the active nav item you will need a method on the next page to somehow recognise which item should be highlighted and add a class to it - presumably in a similar manner to the above does, getting the segment from the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! @Rory McCrossan